# Is it possible to have a chain reaction of locks in DB?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Maybe I misunderstood the nature of table locks, but I was wondering if it was possible to have a chain reactions of locks on some tables

I don't know how big a DB scope can be, but consider about 200 db tables, and hundreds/thousands of stored procedures.
If at some point one procedure is locking one table, and therefore some other procedure encounter the lock, but it somehow manage to lock another table because of the first lock, and this over and over until a point where all procedure are blocking each others in some infinite chain.

So we get locks and timeout everywhere until all service calling these procedures are stopped and restarted with a fix on the root cause on the initial procedure.

Is this scenario possible in anyway ?

Comment: A deadlock might fit into what you are describing, and yes, they can happen.

Comment: That's why developers should take care of queries and transactions and *not* use eg long transactions or global connections. Both ADO.NET and EF, EF Core, NHibernate, are built to work without a constantly open connection so such lock explosions should never happen - unless eg someone run table defragmentation while every service was running. Bad coding practices like using `NOLOCK` to cover up concurrency issues take *more locks at the table level* too, which can result in everything freezing even if only a few rows were modified per table

Comment: For example `If at some point one procedure is locking one table` why should a stored procedure do that, unless it's a maintenance stored procedure?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right ! I was referencing lock and deadlock as the same term, I didnt know the deadlock was object waiting for another. So a dead lock can definitely trigger another one right ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos insert and update do lock rows, no ? So if some parallel services are using the same procedure, they should always hit different resources, that's for sure. But if one of the service ultimately fails at its job and produce a lock, affecting other services that request the same table, the deadlock will occurs

Comment: @BMA they lock *rows*, not entire tables. So they shouldn't cause widespread blocking - unless something maintains those locks for a long time, like an open transaction or connection. `if one of the service ultimately fails at its job and produce a lock` why should it? For starters, if a process dies, the connection dies and the locks are released. Unless the service somehow hides the exception and keeps the global connection open? Use SSMS's Activity Monitor or Extended Events to find which services misbehave

Comment: `if some parallel services` which means? Was there an attempt to "speed up" inserts by trying to execute them in parallel instead of batching them or using BULK INSERT?  Perhaps with an overall TransactionScope to make the operation transactional again? Databases can handle *hundreds* if not thousands of *concurrent* connections easily. Most of the time it's the code that causes blocks and deadlocks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well you know how it is, it should not fail, but sometime it does, without crashing the whole process.
Bulk insert is out of the option because in my case, the flow of data is purely consistant and having one more step would only slow down the whole thing.

Maybe we derivate a bit too much from the original question, but I'm still not sure how a simple select could ever cause a lock on a table... Could this select take so much time, the cpu overheat and slow other insert/update/select ? causing deadlock ?